# Extract data inside a Html tag using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

How to extract only the Date using Jsoup

```
<p class="byline">
   <a href="https://www.india.com/author/newsdesk/">India.com News Desk</a>
   November 12, 2020 9:31 AM IST                                        
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code sir

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element byline = document.getElementsByClass("byline").first();
String[] array = byline.html().split(">");
String txtDate = array[2];
```

Comment: India.com News Desk this line is also included in the output I want only the date